# I am trying to log the elements of my submit buttons form but it I cannot see anything in the console browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to log the elements of my submit buttons form but it I cannot see anything in the console browser.

```
 $("#signupform").submit(function(event){
        //prevented default php processing
        event.preventDefault();
        //collect user inputs
        event.preventDefault();
        var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
        console.log(datatopost);
        

    });
```

Comment: You don't need to call `event.preventDefault()` twice.

Comment: If you're not seeing the log message, the function is probably not running. Maybe there's an earlier error in your code that prevented this event listener from being added.

Comment: What happens when you click on the form's submit button? Is the form submitted?

Comment: thanks Barmar. it was a typo but it still not working

Comment: i try isset() but nothing showing up

Comment: `isset()` is not a JavaScript function.

Comment: What if you just do `console.log("in submit handler")` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: I still suspect the problem is that the event handler is never being added. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: i console.log("in submit handler") this but still

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of form it is. You probably have an error somewhere else in the code, and it's preventing this code from running.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it by changing the event from submit to click
here it is:

```
$('#signupform').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var datatopost= $(this).serializeArray();
   console.log(datatopost);

})
```